# Java Scanner useDelimiter() Method

Tags: java

```
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\.|(?<=\\d{2})");
    System.out.print("Enter dms: ");
    degrees = scanner.next();
    minutes = scanner.next();
    seconds = scanner.next();
```

An input of 36.5212 returns seconds = 1, not seconds = 12. How would I correct my scanner.useDelimeter method? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample input and sample desired output?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the regex `\.|(?<=\d{2})` is matching the position between the `1` and the `2`, because at the position `36.521|2` (current position indicated by the `|` character), there are two digits to the left (the string `21`).

You can change the regex to the following:

```
\.|(?<=\.\d{2})
```

This way you enforce it, that the valid positions are only the `.` character itself or the position `36.52|12`, where there is the positive look-behind of `.\d\d` (the string `.52`). The position `36.521|2` will not match anymore because the `.` character is missing between `5` and `2`.

You can check the issue with your regex with the visualization from https://regex101.com/r/fL3kyA/1:

[image: regex visualization]

As you see by the pink bars, it finds three positions, even though you only want one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and solution!